# Placing Object Icons on the Object-List of an APP in Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Can we attach respective Object Icons to the Object-List of an APP in Lightning Experience?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get metadata information about the apps and their tabs available in the Salesforce user interface by executing a describe call in Apex. Also, you can get more detailed information about each tab. The methods that let you perform this are the describeTabs Schema method and the getTabs method in Schema.DescribeTabResult, respectively.

```
//Map of objectname and icon
Map<String,String> objectIconMap = new Map<String,String>();
// Get tab set describes for each app
List<Schema.DescribeTabSetResult> tabSetDesc = Schema.describeTabs();

// Iterate through each tab set describe for each app and display the info
for(DescribeTabSetResult tsr : tabSetDesc) {
    // Display tab info for the Sales app
    if (appLabel == 'RecrutingDemo') {
        List<Schema.DescribeTabResult> tabDesc = tsr.getTabs();
        System.debug('-- Tab information for the Sales app --');
        for(Schema.DescribeTabResult tr : tabDesc) {
            System.debug('getLabel: ' + tr.getLabel());
            System.debug('getIconUrl: ' + tr.getIconUrl());
            System.debug('getIcons: ' + tr.getIcons());
            System.debug('getMiniIconUrl: ' + tr.getMiniIconUrl());
            System.debug('getSobjectName: ' + tr.getSobjectName());
            System.debug('getUrl: ' + tr.getUrl());
            System.debug('isCustom: ' + tr.isCustom());

            /*****fill the map with details*******/
            objectIconMap.put(tr.getSobjectName(),tr.getIconUrl());
    }            
}
```

[Describing Tabs Using Schema Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describeTabs.htm)